# Applozic SDK Notification won't show if we close/kill app

Tags: android, push-notification, applozic

Integrated Applozic in android app, and also tried sample app,

notification for any message only works if app is open or in background.

It does not work if we close/kill application (remove from background).

All the setup for firebase key etc is done exactly as given in doc.

And it is correct I think as notification works if app is open.

I think service which works to show notification stops when we close app, How to keep it running?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share us the applicationKey and one login userId,app build.gradle file,android manifest file  and also  which  apploizc sdk version your using currently?

Comment: Yes, let me send

Comment: @SunilKumar  Where should I send build.gradle and manifest file ?

Comment: support@applozic.com

Comment: @SunilKumar  sent email, please check

Comment: thanks for info it has been replied